# Visual studio asp.net publish: does it drop current online users

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, publishing

Using VS2008sp1: trying to find a reliable way (or proper way) to update a running web application (ASP.NET 3.5sp1) without losing current user sessions/context.

I know users can get a busy message during the publish which is ok. Question is: does IIS reset sessions? or lose any context that the current users are in? Can this be phased in? or can I adjust my architecture to help this.

My only current solution now is to do it 'after' hours, but once its 24x7 - when is that? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you update the web application the app domain is terminated and a new one is started, so unless you are storing user state elsewhere, your users will lose their session state.

A couple of ways you can fix this are:

1. Store user session out of process
   (could be a database). As long as
   this state is persisted somewhere,
   you can restore the user's state
   from the web app itself when the app comes back up.
2. Don't store state/session values
   anywhere other than perhaps a
   cookie or a querystring. That way no state is lost
   when the app is restarted.